# Did Two Eagles tell this joke?

Tags: quotes

Robert "Two Eagles" Green of the (reorganised) [Patawomeck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patawomeck) Native American tribe is widely quoted with a joked about progress:

- [Where the white man went wrong](http://www.examiner.com/article/where-the-white-man-went-wrong), Examiner, 2012

> “Indian Chief, “Two Eagles,” was asked by a white government official, “You have observed the white man for 90 years. You’ve seen his wars and his technological advances. You’ve seen his progress, and the damage he’s done.”
>
> The Chief nodded in agreement.
>
> The official continued, “Considering all these events, in your opinion, where did the white man go wrong?”
>
> The Chief stared at the government official for over a minute and then calmly replied. “When white man find land, Indians running it. No taxes, No debt, Plenty buffalo, Plenty beaver, Clean Water; Women did all the work, Medicine man free. Indian man spend all day hunting and fishing; All night having sex.”
>
> Then the chief leaned back and smiled. “Only white man dumb enough to think he can improve system like that.”

examiner.com mentions that

> Even though Two Eagles was well known enough to be interviewed for a 2005 movie, "The New World" and for the “Conversations with Crazy Horse” web book and audio book combo, no biographies for this chief exist online.

Is this a genuine quote from Two Eagles?

Comment: Note: I originally read this as some historic story from 90 years after the European settlement of North America. But, as the Wikipedia account and the 2005 interview revealed, Two Eagles was an activist in the 1990s. This is a contemporary story.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @MarchHo - because this looks like an attempt to give more airtime and publicity to a racist (and sexist, for that matter) parable, as opposed to a genuine attempt to find an answer to a practical question.

Comment: @DVK: Whether or not it is perceived as racist, it is still correct. Please leave politically correct, i.e. biased arguments out of this.

Comment: @MarchHo - note the stated reason for the bounty.

Comment: @DVK: Please stop using strawman attacks.

Comment: @DVK While I find your reasoning plausible (relatively new poster put up a bounty for a rather trivial and unimportant sounding question), I don't agree that you should assume bad faith in this case. Unless there is very clear evidence of bad faith, I would just leave the question alone instead of downvoting it.

Comment: @MarchHo People aren't required to explain why they downvote, and they easily can downvote without explaining. If you ask for an explanation for a downvote and they answer, IMO you should (on principle) be grateful for their answer (to encourage downvoters' answers to that question in the future) and not argue that the voter's reasoning is wrong (which may discourage answers to that question in the future).

Comment: @ChrisW While I can see why many (or even most) people would do that, I would not personally mind being corrected if my reasoning is wrong or otherwise invalid. I hope this mindset of not assuming the worst can be adopted by more people.

Comment: @DVK while I dislike the line of thinking in this anecdote, the line of thinking is reasonably common, and worth critically examining. I think checking the authenticity of this quote is not an awful way to do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, this joke/quote has no relationship to Chief Robert "Two Eagles" Green of the Patawomeck tribe.

The actual Chief Robert "Two Eagles" Green is much younger than 90 years old and does not speak in broken English.

He is Robert Parrish Green who [graduated](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1298&dat=19650612&id=muVLAAAAIBAJ&sjid=LosDAAAAIBAJ&pg=7336,6750008&hl=en) from James Monroe high school, Fredericksburg, Virginia, class of 1965 ([additional source](http://www.fredsign.com/jmhs/Book35.htm)).  He received a B.A. in history and political science from University of Richmond in 1969. ([The Free Lance-Star 9 June 1969, page 2](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1298&dat=19690609&id=WPJNAAAAIBAJ&sjid=pYoDAAAAIBAJ&pg=5494,4191194&hl=en))

He still [lives in Fredericksburg, VA](https://commonwealth.virginia.gov/virginia-indians/tribe-contact-information/).

The basic flaw of the article linked in the OP, is taking a joke that has circulated around the internet for years, with only the name "Two Eagles", and associating it with an actual person that goes by that name.

Also, the article linked in the OP shows a photograph that has no relationship with Chief Robert "Two Eagles" Green.

A genuine photograph is available at:

http://www.savecrowsnest.org/discovery_days.htm

A genuine recording of an interview with Robert. P. Green, now Chief Emeritus is also available at:

http://staffordhistorical.org/voices-stafford/#rpg